# Selecting 10 times the number of treatment observations from the control using matchit?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, matching

I have 10,000 observations in the control and 500 in the treatment population. I want to select 5,000 from control which match best with the 500 in the treatment.

Right now, using `matchit`, I am getting 500 in control. This is 1x the treatment observations, but I want 10x the treatment observations.

If `matchit` doesn't work for this case, then any other `R` package which does this job also works.

Comment: Your terminology is unclear here. What do you mean by 'control' and 'test'? These are not opposites.

Comment: By "test" i meant the treatment population. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matchit(..., ratio = 10)`. The `ratio` parameter is the ratio of control to treated in each matched subclass (i.e., each "pair").

Answer (score 0):

Use ratio in your matchit package. matchit(..., data = , method = , ratio = 10). When you don't add ratio, its defaulted to 1.